# How to dynamically create a return statement in python

Tags: python

My dictionary was below

I am searching inside a dictionary for dictionary below

```
test=[ { 'id': '1', 'name': 'A', 'businessArea': [ 'Accounting' ], 'Role': [ 'Developer' ], 'Designation': [ 'L2' ] }, { 'id': '2', 'name': 'B', 'businessArea': [ None ], 'Role': [ 'None' ], 'Designation': [ 'None' ] }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'C', 'businessArea': [ 'Engineering' ], 'Role': [ 'Tester', 'Developer' ], 'Designation': [ 'L1' ] } ]
```

My code is working fine for below and returning only one

```
def contains(item, field, values):
    if field:
        item = item.get(field)     
    if item is None:
        return None                
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return item in values       
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return any(contains(v, None, values) for v in item)  

def validate(d):
    return contains(d, 'businessArea', ['Accounting']) and contains(d, 'Designation', ['L2'])
result = [d for d in test if validate(d)] 
print(result)
```

I got one output for above code which is correct

`search_dict` will dynamically come to me, so I wrote below code, but i am getting full test dictionary

```
search_dict  = {'businessArea': ['Research'], 'Designation': ['L2']}
return_string = " and ".join([f"contains(d, '{k}', {v})" for k, v in search_dict .items()])


def contains(item, field, values):
    if field:
        item = item.get(field)     
    if item is None:
        return None                
    if isinstance(item, str):
        return item in values       
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return any(contains(v, None, values) for v in item)  
    
def validate(d):
    return_string = " and ".join([f"contains(d, '{k}', {v})" for k, v in search_dict .items()])
    #print (return_string)
    return return_string
result = [d for d in test if validate(d)] 
print(result)
```

I got full dictionary which is not correct.

Any alternate method like `recursion` also is fine for me.

Why am i writing the second case. I don't want to manually write permutation and combination `contains` as like in first case

Comment: what are those f strings supposed to do? if you're trying to actually call `contains` inside an fstring, you need to put that inside a `{}`. `f"contains(d, '{k}', {v})"` <- is incorrect since the `contains` is just part of the string.

Comment: @Chase i tried with return (" and ".join([f"{contains}(d, '{k}', {v})" for k, v in search_dict .items()])), but could not succeed

Comment: that's completely invalid syntax, everything inside the `{}` of an fstring should be valid python syntax. `contains` alone is just a function name, that's not a function call

Comment: @Chase is there any way to do this operation

Comment: you need to explain what you're trying to do first, what is `result` supposed to contain? a list of booleans?

Comment: @Chase my `search_dict  = {'businessArea': ['Research'], 'Designation': ['L2']}` it s dynamically passed dictionary. So according to that i need to run the return statement

Comment: You should provide some cases like if x is input, it should return y

Comment: Just so you know, your second `validate` function returns a `str` like `False and True`, which, in an if statement, will _always_ evaluate to `True`. This is because the `str` has a length greater than 0. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to return the elements of `test` that contain the pairs `key,value` specified by `search_dict`?

In this case, would this work for you?:

```
def validate(d):
    for k,v in search_dict.items():
        if not contains(d, k, v):
            return False
    return True
result = [d for d in test if validate(d)] 
print(result)
```

Note that it is usually not great practice to try to write a string that will be then executed as code.

Comment: is this recursion

Comment: yes, i m trying to return the elements of test that contain the pairs key,value specified by search_dict   /.......   what is if not r continue

Comment: 1) This is not recursion, but simply iteration (over the content of `search_dict`). 2) I meant `if not r: break` and not `if not r: continue`. `continue` means "don't execute the rest of the code for this iteration of the loop, but start the next iteration of the loop". `break` means "get out of the loop (don't go to next iteration)", which is what I wanted here, because as soon as you find one element that is not in `d`, you can stop.

Comment: @Maws 3) In any case, I wrote a simpler solution now. What the code does now is: "iterate over `search_dict`; as soon as you find an element that is not in `d`, return `False`, otherwise go on with the iteration; once you have iterated over all elements of `search_dict`, and they are all in `d`, return `True`."

Comment: your other solution is better i think, there if any one wants to search `or` condition change `r = r and contains(d, k, v)`  to r = r or contains(d, k, v)

Comment: Yeah although in this case it would be more efficient to write `if contains(d,k,v): return True`, and then `return False` if no item is contained in `d`. Besides, look at @a_guest 's solution: it's shorter (it's actually how I would do it... but I thought it was nicer to write something more explicit). In addition you can use `any` instead of `all` if you want to verify that just one item is there.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) in order to verify that all items in the dict obey the condition:

```py
def validate(d):
    return all(contains(d, k, v) for k, v in search_dict.items())
```